# Export Amazon orders

Tags: amazon, export

How can I export/download all my Amazon orders?

Preferably as CSV file, but any common format is fine.

It would be great if it includes:

- order date
- product name
- product URL
- product price

Answer (score 2):

Amazon > Your Account > Download Order Reports

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thank you! -- Unfortunately, this option seems to be only available at *amazon.com* (or, at least not at *amazon.de*). So, I’m still looking for a solution for those Amazon sites that don’t have this option. But your answer is a nice solution for amazon.com.

Answer (score 2):

This is now working for amazon.de too. You just need to create a business account. Then go to Business Konto -> Beschaffungsanalysen  (sorry for German, but he asked especially for amazon.de). There you can select required columns and export it to CSV.